# Why is this math equation showing errors?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Why does this code show errors?
[image]

For this equation I used the code:

```
\begin{equation}
Y_k\big(p+1\big) = 
   \begin{cases}
       +1 \;\;\; if W_k  $>$ 0 \\
       -1 \;\;\; if W_k  $<$ = 0
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

The errors that appear are:

[image]

Comment: Neverhave blank lines in equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.

1. There must be no blank line inside an `equation` environment.
2. You're already in math mode, so `$>$` and `$<$` are misplaced.
3. “if” should not be treated as math.
4. You're missing the alignment point.
5. `<=` should be `\leq`.

As a stylistic remark, there's no need for `\big`. If you really want it, it should be `\bigl(p+1\bigr)`.

```latex
\begin{equation}
Y_k(p+1) = 
\begin{cases}
    +1 & \text{if } W_k > 0 \\
    -1 & \text{if } W_k \leq 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: I would go for `&\text{if \(W_k>0\)}\\...`, but that's fine, too.

Comment: @manooooh I too, but it's perhaps too advanced for the OP.